# How can I make this background as an xml drawable?

Tags: android, background-image, xml-drawable

I want give my app a background and I want create this in an xml file, not an image.
Can someone help me? please.

[image: background here]

Comment: Did you search? Did you try anything? With which results?

Comment: yes, I can make the blue background, but I can't do the white circle ( in the same file xml) I try use s shape, but if I use shape, I can't let the app responsive. Sorry my bad inglish.

Comment: Simply use a blue color for your View container and a white oval with an offset for the View.

Comment: A shape or a VectorDrawable. Or a 9 patch. Or a bitmap. You choose which one fits best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="200px">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#6bcbf4" />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:bottom="900px">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFF8F8F8"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>



</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got It:

```
<item android:top="200px">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF954CFB" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:height="10dp">

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="-500dp" android:bottom="300dp" android:left="-100dp" android:right="-100dp">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="400dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
    </shape>
</item>
```